# How to exclude first row from sorting out Excel column Sort method of Excel.Range

Tags: c#, excel, sorting

I am sorting an Excel Sheet which looks like this

[image: Screenshot of the excel]

This Excel sheet will have other entries like "f7.3.2", "f8.3.1", e.t.c., during the runtime and at the end I would like to sort entire Excel.
I am sorting the entire Excel based on Column "B1" as show in the code below

```
 dynamic fullDataRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
 fullDataRange.Sort(fullDataRange.Columns[2], Ex.XlSortOrder.xlAscending);
```

The output from the above code is

[image]

and in the last row you can find

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what is that I am doing wrong?
I would like to keep the first row as it is and then sort the Excel based on B1 column.
I have also tried to freeze the first row before sorting using the below code. It still did not work.

```
xlWorkSheet.Application.ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 1;
xlWorkSheet.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jeeped Did you mean 
`code`fullDataRange.Sort(fullDataRange.Columns[2], Ex.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Ex.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes);`code`

Comment: I'm not sure (off hte top of my head) how you would bring the **Header** parameter into the [Range.Sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) but that is the VBA method of telling the .Sort that you have a header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay people I changed the *fullDataRange* object from ***dynamic*** to ***Excel.Range***  object and everything works fine!
Below is the code

```
Ex.Range fullDataRange= xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
fullDataRange.Sort(fullDataRange.Columns[2, miss], Ex.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, miss, miss, Ex.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
             miss, Ex.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Ex.XlYesNoGuess.xlGuess, miss, miss,
           Ex.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns, Ex.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin, Ex.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal,
           Ex.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal,
           Ex.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal);
```

Thank you @Jeeped for your comment.

Comment: FYI - might want to clarify that `miss` is `Type.Missing`.